# Django newbie. global name 'RequestContext' is not defined

Tags: python, django

I got a "global name 'RequestContext' is not defined "error on my django project.

Please help me..

Here is my codes.

the home/views.py

```
import os
from django.shortcuts import render_to_response

def home(request):
    return render_to_response('/home.html')
```

and the project urls.py

```
from django.conf import settings
from django.conf.urls.static import static
from django.conf.urls import patterns, include, url
from django.contrib import admin
from home import views

admin.autodiscover()

urlpatterns = patterns( '',
    url(r'^$', 'home.views.home', name='home'),
    url(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),
) + static(settings.STATIC_URL, document_root=settings.STATIC_ROOT)
```

Comment: Please post the full traceback of the error. It will help us find where the issue is.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to import the RequestContext from django.template

```
from django.template import RequestContext

return render_to_response('home.html', context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

Comment: This answer solved the another problem too.. thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Just import `from django.template import RequestContext` to your view.py file and change `render_to_response` to

`return render_to_response('/home.html', context_instance=RequestContext(request))`